# Compass placing or position in a MKMapView?

Tags: swift, mkmapview

I am coding one Location based App by Swift.

I make my MapView can show Compass, but I would like to change the compass location from the right-up corner to the left-down corner.

Does any expert know how to move it?

Thank you in advanced.

Comment: I have no idea why this question was closed in favor of a newer question, particularly as this question has a roughly correct answer . anyway I put in the full correct modern answer on the other question, https://stackoverflow.com/a/78136924/294884

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try to change this:

```
mapView.layoutMargins
```

Or subclass the MKMapView component:

```
import MapKit

class MyMapView: MKMapView {    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        if let compassView = self.subviews.filter({ $0.isKindOfClass(NSClassFromString("MKCompassView")!) }).first {
            compassView.frame = CGRectMake(15, 30, 36, 36)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you verify if the second method still works? I cannot find any view with class `MKCompassView` in the subviews of my instance of MKMapView. The compass is enabled and showing but inaccessible.

Comment: @Ben-Ong The MKCompassView is definitely still a subview of MKMapView, though it's only in the hierarchy when the map is rotated and the compass is shown.  I just checked against iOS 9.1 in the simulator, using XCode's "Debug View Hierarchy".

Comment: Can someone verify this approach works and passes Apple's review? There's no doc on `MKCompassView`, and `MKCompassButton` is only available publicly starting iOS 11. This screams private API access to me.

Comment: Confirmed that: `mapView.layoutMargins = view.safeAreaInsets` worked best for me.

Comment: This also works fine: ```mapView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 64, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 8)```

Comment: Absolutely does not work, for years now.  fully explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78136924/294884

Answer (score 26):

You can do this by setting the compass visibility to false and then adding a new compass

```
mapView.showsCompass = false

let compassBtn = MKCompassButton(mapView:mapView)
compassBtn.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.maxX - 40, y: 20)
compassBtn.compassVisibility = .adaptive
view.addSubview(compassBtn)
```

You can use adaptive visibility so your new compass will behave like the original one.

Comment: This is only available from iOS11, is there a way for iOS 9 and 10 as well?