# Change compass-position in Map

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, compass

I'd like to change the position of the compass like below:

[image: img]

This is what I tried so far but it doesn't seems to be the right way - Yeah, it is not working.

```
if let compassView = self.view.subviews.filter({ ($0.subviews.first?.isKind(of: NSClassFromString("MKCompassView")!))!}).first {
    // set compassView position
}
```

Comment: I have provided a complete solution with Swift 5.0.
<br> Check out [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57009652/4714128)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try contains in IOS < 11

```
if let compassBtn = (mapView.subviews.filter { String(describing:$0).contains("MKCompassView") }.first) {
  print(compassBtn)
 }
```

Also if your deployment target >= IOS 11 you can use `MKCompassButton`

```
 let compassBtn = MKCompassButton(mapView:mapView)
 compassBtn.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 25, y: 25)
 compassBtn.compassVisibility = .visible
 view.addSubview(compassBtn)
```

Edit:

```
if let compassView = (mapView.subviews.filter({ $0 is NSClassFromString("MKCompassView")! }).first) {  }
```

Comment: It looks like the` first code ` is not working either. The second code looks quiet well but I'm still getting `two compass Views` instead of one. How can I fix this? Edit: `Your first code will not print anything out, it's not working however I' trying it.`

Comment: First: Thanks for your response. :-) But tbh your edit is still not working. I'm getting this error:` Consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';' `. Edit: I'm using Swift 4

Comment: Are you still there @Sh_Khan??

Comment: I may try it later and gives you feedback