# How to show MapKit compass?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, compass

Currently the compass only get's shown if **a User applies a rotate-gesture**. Otherwise the compass is hidden.

[image: img1]

---

But it would be nice if my two wishes below were fulfilled!

- Is it possible to display the compass always?
- How to show / hide the compass-view using Swift?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do this quite easily in iOS 11 by using the new [`MKCompassButton`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkcompassbutton) class.

You need to create an instance of `MKCompassButton` and add it to your map view. You can then set its `compassVisibility` property to one of:

- `.visible` - always visible
- `.never` - never visible
- `.adaptive` - the compasss is only visible if the map is rotated away from a North/up orientation.

If you keep a reference to the compass in a property you can change its visibility as you need:

```
mapview.showsCompass = false  // Hide built-in compass

compassButton = MKCompassButton(mapView: mapview)   // Make a new compass
compassButton.compassVisibility = .visible          // Make it visible

mapview.addSubview(compassButton) // Add it to the view

// Position it as required

compassButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
compassButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapview.trailingAnchor, constant: -12).isActive = true
compassButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: mapview.topAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
```

Unfortunately, for prior versions of iOS there is no simple solution. I have seen suggestions that involve [looking through the map view's subviews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343381/how-to-reposition-compass-of-mkmapview/48350333) to try and find the compass view but there seems to be mixed results.

Comment: This is not showing the compass before the first rotate gesture. It is just "creating" a new one.

Comment: The positioning will not let the compass appear before the rotate gesture.

Comment: I took this code directly from a test app. The compass appears as soon as the map appears.

Comment: Would you be so kind to share your app? @Paulw11 Maybe GitHub? I can not find the issue in my code. Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: Thanks so much. I will have a look on your project later, but anyways THANKS!

Comment: @thexande Did you try it on a real device?  It works for me.  Maps can be a bit broken in the simulator.  If you rotate the map in the simulator then the compass appears but this is not required on a real phone.